# How to improve speed execution of coffeescript in rails?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, performance, coffeescript

To increase speed of page loading I`ve implemented creation comments via AJAX. It is simple and not heavyweight.In controller action I have:

```
def create
    @comment = @commentable.comments.new(params_comment)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @comment.save
        flash.now[:notice] = "Your comment added."
        @response = {comment: @comment, model: @commentable}
        format.js { @response }
        format.html { redirect_to @commentable  }
      else
        format.js { render nothing: :true, status: :not_acceptable }
        format.html { redirect_to @commentable, status: :not_acceptable  }
      end
    end
  end
```

and js file:

```
$("<%= escape_javascript( render 'comments/comment', @response)%>").appendTo(".comments").hide().fadeIn(500)
$('.notice-wrapper').html("<%= j(render partial: 'shared/notice') %>")
$('.alert').fadeOut(3000)

if $(".no-comments").css("display") is 'block'
  $(".no-comments").hide()
$(".new_answer").hide()
$(".open").show()
```

But instead of speed up performance I got the opposite effect. Response time through JavaScript  increased on 100-200 ms(~300ms total). Is this normal behavior or I am doing something wrong? Is there any way to improve speed little bit?

My performance test:

[image]

**UPD:**
My performance test with just JS file.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's put aside for the moment my opinion that embedding ERB in CoffeeScript is utterly gross to look at and unmaintainable. It is indisputable that there's a huge performance impact when you generate and compile CoffeeScript on every request.

You also lose any chance at HTTP caching.

My first suggestion would be to separate CoffeeScript from ERB. Populate hidden fields in your ERB with the data you need, and then mine those fields in your CoffeeScript.

But if you must embed ERB in what should be static files, embed the ERB tags in pure JavaScript instead, and let the compiled CoffeeScript use those.

Comment: Could you elaborate more why CoffeeScript ERB is unmaintainable? Thanks!

Comment: It might not be 'unmaintainable' but compiling CoffeeScript on every request should be good enough reason not to do it.

Comment: Sorry, @Billy, I didn't mean to ignore the question, but opinion-based threads are so not what they want to see on here. Happy to take that conversation to Twitter or elsewhere.

Comment: @Vidya, no worries, I didn't mean to challenge you at all but really want to learn something. :) Since you excluded performance in the claim, I would assume the claim also includes javascript erb. I myself don't like that style, so I would like to know your opinion in depth when you claim that. I can't reach your Twitter page through the profile, maybe some misspelling there. Please keep me informed when you have written a post or have a discussion about that. Thanks.

Comment: @Billy, I didn't mean to suggest you had anything on your mind but a discussion. Even if it was a challenge, that's cool. I just corrected the links on my profile, so feel free to tweet anytime. I might blog about it too on the Vidya site.

Answer (score 1):

The code you've written wouldn't really be expected to speed up the request, because Rails still need to process all the ERB etc.  You're still returning rendered HTML and sending it to the browser where it is added to the DOM.

If you wanted to make it 'faster' you could simply render the `@response` as json and deal with it on the client using jQuery or a front end framework.

The code does make it nicer for the user, however, because it doesn't refresh the entire page.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to hook into the form request, and on success, render the new comment, else re-render form with errors. An example:

```
# app/javascripts/comments.coffee

$('#comment-form').bind 'ajax:complete', (data, status, xhr) ->
  // psuedo code
  1. if status is success
       append comment -- $('#comments').append(data.comment)
  2. else
       re-render form with errors -- $('#comment-form').html(data.form)
```

1. Return comment template (comments/comment) and append to comments
2. Update your controller to return the form with JS response if not_acceptable.
3. Note the file is found in app/javascripts/comments.coffee